# Evaluate the number of unique items that happend in a specific column of datafram based on date column and add result to a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[how can calculate the number of unique dealers that happened in a data frame for a for 7 previous days from 10/15/22 and 30 previous days from it and 60 previous days from it the output would be
in the second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjxyQ.png)

[second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDBkF.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to count the number of dealers uniquely that happened in the last column based on each city and product for 7 days,30 days, and 60 days before 10,15/22 and create a data frame like the second picture